# Electronics manual for noobs

Tags: electronics

In my faculty course I didn't have any introduction to electronics... just programming. So I want to start small thinks with the GPIO of the raspberry pi but I even to plug a simple led is not [straightforward](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4357).

Other problem is to interpreter the diagrams, for example, in this [article](http://issuu.com/themagpi/docs/issue_6_final/9) 
how to get the list of material, look into the diagram and finish it like the photo.

There is any manual of electronics for noobs like me?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Electronics for Dummies
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Electronics-Dummies-Edition-Dickon-Ross/dp/0470681780
(The link is for the UK Amazon site, so if you're not in the UK, just search for it on your local Amazon or online bookstore).

It helped me to understand the individual components that were talked about in diagrams.

In terms of that MagPi article, you'll want to look at the stripboard diagram rather than the circuit diagram at the top. The stripboard diagram shows you what to solder more clearly. The other thing is to watch out for projects with "Fritzing" diagrams - these are even clearer.

Fritzing is a piece of open-source software that allows clear and colourful diagrams. http://www.fritzing.org

Apart from that, you could try asking on the Raspberry Pi Foundation forum if you need help on specific projects, particularly those from The MagPi.

Good luck!

Comment: I took a look at the book and it seems to be what I'm looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A classic, comprehensive but aging book that's still a great choice for learning the basics is '[The Art of Electronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics)' by Horowitz and Hill.

According to an interview with Winfield Hill there is an updated 3rd edition in the works slated to be released in late 2013...